# ReferenceError: document is not defined at e2.n2.appendCursorAnimationCss

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular17

I'm getting this below error after every successfull run of the project. I haven't used any animation in this current project.
And I haven't used any thing like `document.getElement........`
I'm creating a demo app in Angular 17 to explore the features of it.
Below I have added the package.json file for the reference.

````
    at e2.n2.appendCursorAnimationCss (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/typed.js/dist/typed.module.js:1:3024)
    at e2.n2.load (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/typed.js/dist/typed.module.js:1:2719)
    at t2 (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/typed.js/dist/typed.module.js:1:4695)
    at NgxTypedJsComponent.ngAfterViewInit (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/ngx-typed-js/fesm2020/ngx-typed-js.mjs:21:18)
    at callHookInternal (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/portfolio/demo/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3523:14)
    at callHook (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3550:13)
    at callHooks (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3505:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3455:9)
    at refreshView (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/dmeo/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13461:21)
    at detectChangesInView (/Users/shubhambhardwaj/demo/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13615:9)```

Here is my Package.json

    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "ngx-typed-js": "^2.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  }
````